# Disabling "Action link" in layout which is referened in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a razor file.cshtml which is using a _mylayout.cshtml. In my _mylayout.cshtml file there are several Action links.

From my razor file.cshtml how do I disable/hide an Action Link in _mylayout.cshtml file ?

```
_mylayout.cshtml
...
..
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Edit", "DetailsFor", null, null)</li>
...
..

my file.cshtml which is using _mylayout.cshtml
...
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details Information";
    Layout = "~/Views/_mylayout.cshtml";
}
....
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't technically. About the only thing you could do is use `ViewBag` to branch the layout code.

```
@if (ViewBag.HideDetailLink == null)
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Edit", "DetailsFor", null, null)</li>
}
```

Then, in your view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.HideDetailLink = true;
}
```

It doesn't actually matter what you set it to here, just that it has some value. By default, of course, it won't have a value (will be null) and the link will be displayed because the condition passes.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to @Chris is to hide it with jquery.  You can do this by giving your ActionLink an ID (htmlAttribute param).

```
@Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Edit", "DetailsFor", null, new { id = "detailsLink" })
```

I created a fiddle to show you how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/bxre7foe/

just add the "hide" method to your _mylayout script block at the bottom:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#detailsLink").hide();
</script>
```